# How do I configure fortify so that it scans even C# code?

Tags: fortify

Using HP fortify I am able to scan java and C code files but C# files are not getting scanned. Does anyone know what is the reason for this? Is there a configuration in fortify that makes it scan C# files? Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fortify SCA works on the Common Intermediate Language (CIL), and therefore supports all of the .NET languages that compile to CIL, including C# and VB .NET.

The easiest way to analyze a .NET application is to use the **"HPE Security Fortify Package for Visual Studio"**, which automates the process of gathering information about the project.

Comment: If I dont have the fortify package  for visual studio , can I download it ? And from where can i download? Thanks for the help. Are there other ways to scan c,c++ and c# using fortify?